# Measuring the association of a variable with 2 different survival outcomes

Tags: survival, competing-risks

I have survival data for a cohort of patients and the outcome is either cardiovascular or non-CV death. I wish to assess whether some variables make it so that the patient is more likely do die from one cause or the other.

This question is much like my own ([Comparing Hazard Rate Ratios for different outcomes on the same sample](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26587/comparing-hazard-rate-ratios-for-different-outcomes-on-the-same-sample)), but 11 years ago with few answers.

From what I cold gather, it seems the most appropriate method for my question would be the Lunn-McNeil one. Though I have seem some published papers using it, I have found surprisingly little information about it (be it on this website or otherwise).

Much of the competing risks literature regards CIC and Fine-Gray methods, which does not seem appropriate for this particular question.

So my questions are:

- Is the Lunn-McNeil the correct method for this situation?
- If so, is it available from statistical packages (R, preferably)? Or is it usually done "by hand", so to speak?

Answer (score 2):

This is a straightforward competing-risks scenario. There are two mutually exclusive "absorbing" events (no return from either event is possible). Cox regression modeling of such data is described in Section 3.1 of the R [multi-state model vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf). I haven't looked at the "Lunn-McNeil" paper in great detail, but at first glance that's paper's "Method B," which models the risks stratified by event type, seems to be similar to the method explained in the R vignette.

As the vignette explains, in this scenario you can get the same Cox regression coefficients by modeling each event type separately, censoring individuals that experience the other event type. That separate-modeling method does not, however, provide correct estimates of the probability of death from each cause over time. The combined analysis described at the beginning of Section 3.1 does.

The Fine-Gray "subdistribution hazard" approach is another choice for this simple competing-risks scenario. Section 4 of the vignette illustrates that approach and its strengths and weaknesses versus the Cox modeling approach. There are several dozen posts on this site discussing [Fine-Gray modeling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=fine+gray).

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Those methods you mention are to estimate, as I understand, the effect of a variable i on outcome X, accounting for competing risks (say, B_iX). 

Say the effect of the same variable i on outcome Y (account for competing risks) is B_iY. What I am actually looking for is a way to assess the relationship B_iX / B_iY ( I mean, it could be any other formulation of this quantity).

Comment: @EduardoMoreira you can simply run tests on functions combining the $\beta_iX$ and $\beta_iY$ estimates for predictor $i$ and outcomes $X$ and $Y$. As the $\beta$ coefficients (in log-hazard scale) are (asymptotically) multivariate normal, after you have done the modeling you can use the coefficient point estimates and their variance-covariance matrix to do such comparisons. The simplest would be to evaluate $\beta_iX - \beta_iY$ to see if they are significantly different. Tests on the ratio $\beta_iX / \beta_iY$ are likely to be problematic, particularly if $\beta_iY$ is close to 0.